# Bold or Recolor on "Ask Question" button

Tags: feature-request

I think that `Ask Question` button font should be **bold** in the "menu" with items:

`Questions`, `Jobs`, `Tags`, `Users`, `Badges`, **`Ask Question`**

... Or at least with **different font color**, since it is an action, not a list like on each other button there.

[image]

Comment: I don't think we really want questions from folks who can't find the "Ask Question" button. If someone can't find the button as it currently looks, I think it's not likely that they can ask a good question.

Comment: Yeah, we don't get enough questions. Let's make it *easier* to ask.

Comment: It's not a question of make it easy for bumb people, it's just a question of good practice. ;-)

Comment: This sounds to me as though its trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist

Comment: You all guys are just assuming that it is for make it easier for users, but it is not for that. Read the question correctly and (I think) you will understand.

Comment: @EASI What merits do you see in action buttons having a different color and shape then non-action buttons? They're all labeled properly.

Comment: It's about user interface standards, like for example Windows menus having `...` after label to identify that they will lead to another window. See? If we do not know all the standard rules, how can we stigmatize a suggestion as if we know it all about everything?

Comment: Funny you should mention that. A lot of people apparently don't understand what an ellipsis means after a command. It doesn't mean that it leads to another window. What it actually means is that the command requires additional information from the user in order to be completed. An "About" box leads to another window, but requires no additional information, and therefore should *not* be suffixed with an ellipsis.

Comment: See, no one here is done with learning.

Comment: I don't see any **actual** benefit from this request

Comment: I went to the GIS SE site in Firefox but the "Ask A Question" link isn't bold there for me. Either way, I think the link here is actually easier to spot than the GIS one because there's less contrast between the background and the text on their site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why should it be like that? I can think of two reasons why you suggested this:

> - This makes the "Ask Question" button easier to find for new users

Thats a horrible reason to make it bold. We want new users to put in effort, research and read our how to ask and help center pages. We don't want asking a question to be as easy as possible, we want people to care before.

> - This makes it less likely to accidentally click it when navigating the rest.

Thats a slightly more valid point but I still think its highly unnecessary.

Comment: This approuch is (from style and templating view) more correct, and also more friendly for new users. Old users get too cocky to accept that kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 12):

Finding that button is likely the easiest part in the process of asking a question. If someone lacks the awareness necessary to find it, they probably won't be able to write a question that'd be well-received either.

Comment: Again:  
It's not a question of make it easy for bumb people, it's just a question of good practice. Because it's a diffetrent thing from the other...